# Is there any way I can transfer tools from backtrack 5 R3 to ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-center, backtrack

**Just curious!** if there is any way i can do that without downloading something.

Comment: Could you perhaps narrow down your question a little bit and specify which specific tools you are looking for on Ubuntu that aren't there now?

Answer (score 1):

Some of them are already available in ubuntu repos

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be able to copy binaries / files / libs from backtrack to Ubuntu, but, this is inadvisable for several reasons.

First, it is not ideal to install packages outside of apt (your package manager). See - https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Package_management_system Although the link is for Fedora, it is a great review of the advantage of package managers.

Second, how would you keep the tools up to date? You would have to install them from source, so might as well start there.

Third, Backtrack is NOT ubuntu. It runs a custom kernel, so you are likely to run into problems.